# How do I apply code to a dynamically created element

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code works only if the table is already present in the document upon page load. I however want it to apply on a dynamically created table.
Can this be done?

```
 var colNumber=22


for (var i=0; i<colNumber; i++)
{
  var thWidth=$("#tbl").find("th:eq("+i+")").width();
  var tdWidth=$("#tbl").find("td:eq("+i+")").width();      
  if (thWidth<tdWidth)                    
      $("#tbl").find("th:eq("+i+")").width(tdWidth);
  else
      $("#tbl").find("td:eq("+i+")").width(thWidth);           
}
```

The table is created in the following way:

```
    function loadFile(event){
    alasql('SELECT * FROM FILE(?,{headers:false})',[event],function(data){  
        var keys = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            for (var categoryid in data[i]) {
                var category = data[i][categoryid];
                keys.push(categoryid);
            }
        }

        keysConverted = keys.map(foo);
        var vMin = Math.min.apply(null, keysConverted);
        var vMax = Math.max.apply(null, keysConverted);
        var start = vMin-1 
        var ColNeeded = vMax - vMin+1;

        var arrExcel2Table = '<table id="tbl">';
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            arrExcel2Table = arrExcel2Table + '<tr>';
                for (var j = 0; j < ColNeeded; j++){
                    cellValue = data[i][number2Letter(j+start)];
                    if (typeof cellValue === "undefined"){
                        cellValue = '';
                    }
                    arrExcel2Table = arrExcel2Table + '<td>' + cellValue + '</td>';
                }
            arrExcel2Table = arrExcel2Table + '</tr>';  
        }
        arrExcel2Table = arrExcel2Table + '</table>';   
        document.getElementById('excel_table').innerHTML = arrExcel2Table;
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Look at the [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

Comment: Well, you're using ids (`#tbl`) - So NO. Unless you use classes

Comment: wrap the code in a function and call that function after the creation of the dynamic table and also as @AlonEitan mentioned use classes

Comment: can you share the code that dynamically creates the element?

Comment: excuse my ignorance, but what would be the difference if I would have used classes rather than ID's?

Comment: @juntapao I added the code that creates/uploads a new table

Comment: @Dummy This is a valid question - IDs are for **UNIQUE** elements in the HTML, and classes can be applied to more than one element. If you have `<table class="tbl"></table>` then you'll select it with `$('.table')` - And it will return all the elements matching this class

Answer (score 0):

Create a function you want to run and add an event from the dynamic element.  For example

```
arrExcel2Table = arrExcel2Table + '<td>' + cellValue + '</td>';
```

can be replaced by

```
arrExcel2Table = arrExcel2Table + '<td onclick="myFunction();">' + cellValue + '</td>';
```

Above code will call the function you created

```
myFunction() {
   alert();
}
```

Comment: Yeah, should work, except that `onclick` attribute is a bad practice. You should properly bind a click event listener after the creation of the table.

Comment: yes, that's just an example because I don't know what is the event that @Dummy wants

Comment: Look at their first code snippet. They basically adjusts the width of the cells. They don't attach any event listener or click or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Just create your table, *then* apply whatever code you want to it :

```
$('#excel_table').html(arrExcel2Table);
adjustWidth()

function adjustWidth(){

    var $tbl = $("#tbl"); // And cache your jQuery objects!! Massive performance boost

    for (var i=0; i<colNumber; i++)
    {
       var $th = $tbl.find("th:eq("+i+")"),
          $td = $tbl.find("td:eq("+i+")"),
          thWidth = $th.width(),
          tdWidth = $td.width();    

      if (thWidth<tdWidth)                    
          $th.width(tdWidth);
      else
          $td.width(thWidth);           
    }
}
```

Comment: this is the answer, i was confused by the question earlier, explanation of this is the creation of the element, it should be `$('#excel_table').html(arrExcel2Table);` in order to work.